# Two vector fields are cojugate but not take orbits

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

Let $X$ and $Y$ be $C^1$ vector feilds on $R^m$. Suppose that $0$ is an attracting hyperbolic singularity for $X$ and $Y$. Show that there exists a homemorphism $h$ of a neighborhood of origin which conjugate the diffeomorphisms $X1$ and $Y1$ but does not take orbits of $X$ to orbits of $Y$.

Comment: Looks like homework to me...

Comment: i see Stability of singularity in singular holomorphic foliation but i think  different by my questions